# Django models ForeignKey on_delete attribute: full meaning?

Tags: django, django-models

Here some models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, db_index=True) 
    birthday = models.DateField()

class Photo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/photo')
```

Let's say a user has 10 photos (10 objects of `Photo` model). When user deletes himself will all those 10 `Photo` database rows delete themselves automatically? (I've read docs, but English is not my native language, so I didn't understand everything about the [`on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) attribute.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

that's the default behaviour, yes. you can change this behaviour with [`on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete)

to get an illustration of this, try deleting a userprofile in the admin. it first shows a warning page, listing all related objects that will also get deleted

Comment: I don't want change this behaviour - I need it! And what if delete user not from admin pannel, but command line - effect will be the same?

Comment: effect is the same. Note however, that by default, the actual files store in Photo.photo will *not* be deleted

Answer (score 202):

I'll go through the values for `on_delete` as they apply to this case. As it notes in the docs, these are all in that `models` module, so you'd use it as `models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`, etc.

These rules apply however you delete an object, whether you do it in the admin panel or working directly with the `Model` instance. (But it won't take effect if you work directly with the underlying database in SQL.)

- `CASCADE`: when you delete the `UserProfile`, all related `Photo`s will be deleted too. This is the default. (So in answer to that aspect of your question, yes, if you delete your user account the photos will be deleted automatically.)
- `PROTECT`: this will stop you from deleting a `UserProfile` with related `Photo`s, raising a `django.db.models.ProtectedError` if you try. The idea would be that the user would need to disassociate or delete all `Photo`s before they could delete their profile.
- `SET_NULL`: when you delete the `UserProfile`, all associated `Photo`s will still exist but will no longer be associated with any `UserProfile`. This would require `null=True` in the `ForeignKey` definition.
- `SET_DEFAULT`: when you delete the `UserProfile`, all associated `Photo`s will be changed to point to their default `UserProfile` as specified by the `default` attribute in the `ForeignKey` definition (you could use this to pass "orphaned" photos off to a certain user - but this isn't going to be common, `SET_NULL` or `SET()` will be much more common)
- `SET()`: when you delete the `UserProfile`, the target of the `Photo`s' `ForeignKey` will be set to the value passed in to the `SET` function, or what it returns if it is a callable. (Sorry, I haven't explained that well, but the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET) have an example which explains better.)
- `DO_NOTHING`: when you delete the `UserProfile`, all related `Photo`s will remain unaltered, thus having a broken reference, unless you have used some other SQL to take care of it.

(Also, `on_delete` isn't a method. It's an attribute of the `ForeignKey` field.)

Comment: I tried CASCADE but when I deleted the Photos the UserProfile got deleted and I tried PROTECT when I tried to delete the Photos it raised an error. I was wondering if this is the side effect of the on_delete attribute on the other end of the relationship. Particularly for the PROTECT, how could you delete all the Photos so that you can delete the UserProfile if the Protected error is raised?