# What parameters does Django's models.DO_NOTHING expect?

Tags: python, django

I've searched [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) but I haven't found any explanation of the parameters.

The implementation of the `DO_NOTHING` does exactly that, so it shouldn't matter what I'm passing in, but for other methods (such as [CASCADE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CASCADE)) they're actually used.

The closest explanation I've found is [a discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543877/django-models-foreignkey-on-delete-attribute-does-it-really-delete-all-related) of CASCADE.

What datatypes are `collector`, `field`, `sub_objs`, and `using`, and what values do I pass?

**EDIT:**

I'm using it in my model, like so:

```
class Office(models.Model):

    #   Office locations have a name, and a location.

    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    location = models.OneToOneField(
        GeoLocation,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING(None, None, None, None)
    )
```

Comment: Why would you want to call this? It's just a possible value of `on_delete` so that django knows what to do on delete.

Comment: I don't believe those are meant to be called by the user. You pass it into the `models.ForeignKey` constructor as a reference and that calls it, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: In my model, I'm using it. I've added an example to my question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You shouldn't be *calling* `models.DO_NOTHING`, you should just be passing it as a value:

```
location = models.OneToOneField(
    GeoLocation,
    on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING
)
```

The fact that it's a function is an implementation detail, not part of the API, which is why those parameters are undocumented.